# CSS Background image will not display correctly in the center

Tags: html, css

I have a 1px X 1px image I made, to display inside a div, whose height will be set using jQuery. The div and the image is to serve as a separator line between the div to the left and right of it. But, no matter what, the image will never show up. I can confirm the image loads (using F12 developer tools).

The end result is to have a 1px wide x Xpx high image in the center (horizontal) of the div. The height will be set by jQuery.

What wrong am I doing?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Background Image Test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.m {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    background-image: url("/resources/images/hr-px-x.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-position:center;
    height:200px;
    width:1px;
}
</style>

<body>

<div>
    <div class="m"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bm47L5hr/)

Comment: What about making fiddle?

Comment: did you tried with an image tag instead of div with background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Use the `background` property instead of `background-image`

2) You need to repeat the image down the y axis so use `repeat-y` on your background

```
.m {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/1x1) center center repeat-y;
    height:200px;
    width:1px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/bm47L5hr/16/)**

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. BTW, do we need width:1px? The image is 1px anyway.

Comment: @Norman - You're right, you don't need width: 1px - but that depends on how wide you want the container to be. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/bm47L5hr/20/

Comment: The repeat-y is nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/za4tf0zf/)

```
.m {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    background: url("/resources/images/hr-px-x.jpg") no-repeat center;
    height:200px;
    width:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setting you width of the element .m to be 1px wide make it instead 20px wide with a padding of 0px

```
.m {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:0px;
    background-image: url("/resources/images/hr-px-x.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-position:center;
    height:200px;
    width:20px;
}
```